# data transfer between 2 devices using tcp/ip in python which are under different networks

Tags: protocols

I am using 2 devices, one is my PC connected to a wifi and another one is virtual PC provided by my company, which is connected to a ethernet.Now how can i transfer the data between these 2 devices using tcp/ip protocol in python?I transfered the data from one machine to other machine if they connected to same network, but this time they are multiple networks.

I want the communication between devices under different networks. In my case one is wifi and another one is ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your Python code goes, there is **no difference** between using TCP/IP in the same network and TCP/IP across networks. (After all, it is literally the job of IP to make network boundaries invisible to the programmer.) You still use the same .bind() and .connect() and you still specify addresses and ports exactly the same way.

Your company network administrators will have taken care of setting up IP routing across networks within the organization (and they *should* have taken care of opening up firewall configuration to let you do your work). If they haven't – you need to talk to them first; that's not a programming issue.

(Note that Ethernet/Wi-Fi boundaries do not always correspond to IP boundaries – the fact that one system is on Ethernet and the other isn't does not immediately indicate that the IP networks are different; a single IP network could actually be extended across both, just like it's already done with your home wifi. Perhaps unlikely in your case at the company network, but it's possible that they're both in the same IP network.)